# Преобразование времени python

Tags: python, datetime

У меня есть время в формате строки и его надо преобразовать в формат "ДД.ММ.ГГГГ", т. е. чтобы осталось только "05.08.2021". Все попытки приводят к ошибкам.

И ещё, с символом "T" надо как-нибудь по особенному обращаться или его можно просто заменить на пробел?

Как мне правильно преобразовать строку в время?

Первый вариант

```
import datetime

day = "2021-08-05T23:56:44.233856"
day_x = datetime.datetime.strptime(day, '%d.%m.%Y').date()

print(day_x)
```

Второй вариант

```
import datetime

day = "2021-08-05T23:56:44.233856"
day_x = datetime.datetime.strptime(day, '%d.%m.%Y')

print(day_x)
```

Возникающая ошибка

```
ValueError: time data '2021-08-05T23:56:44.233856' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y'
```

Я пытался заменить "T" на пробел с помощью

```
day = day.replace('T', ' ')
```

но ничего не изменилось

Comment: Прежде чем преобразовать в правильный формат, надо сперва распарсить с правильным форматом же. `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как написали **Roman Konoval** и **andreymal** можно считать дату и время с помощью `datetime.datetime.strptime()`, но в данном случае формат даты и времени соответствует ISO 8601, что позволяет использовать встроенный метод [`datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat):

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2021-08-05T23:56:44.233856')
```

Дальше уже по классике:

```
d = datetime.datetime.strftime(dt, '%d.%m.%Y')  # 05.08.2021
```

Answer (score 2):

`strptime` - преобразовывает строку в объект `datetime`. Второй параметр это формат, который будет использован для парсинга.

Так что, как указал [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal), нужно правильно задать формат, в котором у вас исходная строка:

```
day_x = datetime.datetime.strptime(day, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Теперь в `day_x` у вас `datetime`. Его можно превратить в `date`:

```
>>> day_x.date()
datetime.date(2021, 8, 5)
```

или отформатировать в строку

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(day_x, '%d.%m.%Y')
'05.08.2021'
```