# Как преобразовать строку во время?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, время

Как с помощью `strptime` преобразовать строку вида `'2021-08-05T19:34:08+03:00'` в формат `datetime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [73]: from datetime import datetime as DT

In [74]: DT.strptime("2021-08-05T19:34:08+03:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
Out[74]: datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 19, 34, 8, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=10800)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Было [вчера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1314192/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-python), но раз начали отвечать, то здесь нужно использовать [`datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat):

```
import datetime

t = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2021-08-05T19:34:08+03:00')
print(type(t))  # Тип t
print(t)  # Значение

# <class 'datetime.datetime'>
# 2021-08-05 19:34:08+03:00
```